# How write exists sql clause in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I translate the sql query below into a map reduce query for mongodb.

```
select
    o_orderpriority, 
    count(*) as order_count
from 
    orders
where 
    o_orderdate >= date '1993-07-01'
    and o_orderdate < date '1993-07-01' + interval '3' month
    and exists (
        select 
        *
        from 
        lineitem
        where 
        l_orderkey = o_orderkey
        and l_commitdate < l_receiptdate
    )
group by 
    o_orderpriority
order by 
    o_orderpriority;
```

And the following map reduce query:

```
db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: "orders",
    query: {
        o_orderdate: {'$gte': new Date("July 01, 1993")},
        o_orderdate: {'$lt': new Date("Oct 01, 1993")}
    },
    map: function Map() {

                for(var i in this.o_lineitem) {
                    if( this.o_lineitem[i].l_commitdate < this.o_lineitem[i].l_receiptdate) {
                        emit( this.o_orderpriority, 1 );
                    }
                }

        },
    reduce: function(key, values) {
                var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    count += values[i];
                }
                return count;
            },
    out: 'query004'
});
```

Look that o_linetem is an embedded array in orders collection.

Well the results are:

In SQL:

```
1-URGENT            10594
2-HIGH          10476
3-MEDIUM            10410
4-NOT SPECIFIED 10556
5-LOW           10487
```

In the other side MongoDB result:

```
{ "_id" : "1-URGENT", "value" : 29215 }
{ "_id" : "2-HIGH", "value" : 29020 }
{ "_id" : "3-MEDIUM", "value" : 28616 }
{ "_id" : "4-NOT SPECIFIED", "value" : 29253 }
{ "_id" : "5-LOW", "value" : 28765 }
```

What happen? What i did wrong in map reduce?

Comment: $exits ? I'm not entirely sure what your SQL is doing but I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting each orderpriority multiple times if there are multiple lineitems in the order that didn't meet the expected commit date.

You are not doing that in your SQL statement - exists clause only checks there is at least one line item that didn't meet the commit date.

If you want to do the equivalent in map/reduce then you should add a `return;` statement after you successfully emit for each order document.

Comment: you could also simplify the whole thing by adding exists equivalent to your query to begin with in which case your map is just a single line emit(this.o_orderpriority,1);

Comment: indeed i was emiting the same orders multiple times. Thank you so much one more time @asya-kamsky